# Iterate and display Rails flash error messages on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to iterate over several error messages that might exist in my rails app

```
format.html do
  flash[:error] = @policy.errors
  redirect_to new_policy_path
end
```

while the render flash views looks like this.

```
<% if flash[:error] %>
  <% flash[:error].full_messages.each do |name, message| %>
    <%=message%>
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

I believe the syntax is wrong. So I need the proper code syntax to render error views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `policy` is ActiveRecord model, you can pass error object from controller through flash object

```rb
flash[:errors] = @policy.errors
```

And iterate in the view

```
<% flash[:errors]&.each do |error| %>
  <%= error.full_message %>
<% end %>
```